# Using Nightcode IDE with Clojure

Tags: clojure

I just started to learn Clojure in my free time and for fun. I installed Leiningen and I have the REPL working on the Windows command. But I wanted to use an IDE and downloaded [Nightcode](https://nightcode.info/) . But I am having problems with lack of Java experience and lack of documentation.

I tried to read [Leiningen documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md) but that did not make much sense either. I know I am not understanding the basics. When I click run on Nightcode I just get this result

```
Running...
Compiling my-project.core
Hello, World!
```

I know this is a very newbee question but can anyone direct me to the right place about how to enter some Clojure functions and run it and see the result in Nightcode? I was expecting to see something as easy as Python IDLE but this is very different.

Thanks.

---

**Re Jared314's answer:**

Now I have this code on the top window:

```
(ns newclojureproject.core
  (:gen-class))

(+ 1 2 3)
```

I click `Run with REPL` and I don't see the result for sum but this

```
my-first-project.clj=> Running...
Compiling my-first-project.clj
Running with REPL...
nREPL server started on port 51595 on host 127.0.0.1
REPL-y 0.2.1
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

my-first-project.clj=> Running...

=== Finished ===

=== Finished ===
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think, if you want to see the output of the code in your file (upper-right pane), you should click "Run" not "Run with REPL" @oaks Let me know if I'm wrong; but I believe "Run" runs your code, whereas "Run with REPL" doesn't run anything; but it just opens a REPL that has access to your program's functions.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the author of Nightcode so I may be able to help. The Run with REPL button is the equivalent of running "lein repl" on the command line. It should bring up a prompt where you can type in clojure commands within the context of your project. It appears that you may have clicked several buttons in rapid succession, so the prompt wasn't available.

Keep in mind that if you just want a simple REPL to try Clojure commands in, just use the one in the bottom left of the window. It's essentially the same thing, except it's always-on and doesn't have access to any project's namespace. I added it precisely for these situations where you just want a quick way to try a command out.

If you have other questions, feel free to ask here or on the [Nightcode subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Nightcode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a shame that I cannot make this work because I like the interface much better than Light Table. There is no problem with the REPL on the bottome left, that works. I guess I don't understand what the top frame is for. I enter a simple function in it like `(+ 1 2)` and I want to run it and want to see the result. Where that result should appear?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait; I wasn't notified that you wrote this comment so I didn't see it until now. I'm not really sure what you mean by "top frame". Where did you type the function? Please make a new text post on the Nightcode subreddit and we can discuss it.

Comment: Maybe you should type `(println (+ 1 2))` to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Run with REPL`, and when you make modifications to the files, the `Reload` button next to it. Create your project and add a new clj file in your src/my_project/ directory, add the `ns` statement at the top of the file, and `Run with REPL`.

As you add functions to the file, and save the file, click the `Reload` button to make your changes available to the REPL. (Note: the `Reload` button will only work when a file in the project has been changed and saved.) There are some limits to what kinds of changes you can reload, because of the limits of the underlying JVM. When you change project dependencies, in the project.clj file, you may need to click `Stop` and then `Run with REPL` again.

I also found a strange issue with my Nightcode REPL where occasionally some statements, are not executed the first time. I worked around that issue by pressing enter, to get back to the prompt, and executing it a second time, with the up arrow and enter.

Comment: Thanks. I am still having problems. I edited the question if you can take a look. And also what does `ns` statement do?

Comment: I'm wondering how you use other Leiningen commands from NightCode, for example lein deps ?

Answer (score 0):

The only quirk I have with Night code, it never closes the parenthesis for you.  Light tables use of Rainbow parenthesis is a big thing for a language like Clojure, its a great visual aid.  Other than that I really enjoy its integrations points with Leiningen for building, testing and working with the repl.  Light table still suffers from stability issues for me, I tend to break it alot and end up having to restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Nightcode is the worst IDE I ever used. Save doesn't work, neither Undo or Redo. It doesn't have a menu for Copy paste you need to use the shortcuts as if we are still in the 80's. It works as slow as if your computer is 15 years older. It lags ALOT. What should aspiring Clojureians use, Emacs? Notepad++? I really expected something like Clojure to have a real IDE in the real sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just click on the `Run with REPL`command which is the third tab below the code and the REPL will be started.
2. Now click on the `InstaREPL` which is fourth tab above your code/

Now Whatever you write in the editor, you can see its result just on the left of your editor in the green color.
If there is any error/Exception, it will be shown in red color.

Hope this helps you!