# LightTable asking to install JDK while it is already installed (Windows 8 running as Windows 7)

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I tried [NightCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081817/using-nightcode-ide-with-clojure) but couldn't make it work. Now I learned about LightTable and I am trying that but without success.

I already have the JDK installed but LightTable cannot find it and it is asking to install JDK. How do I tell LightTable that JDK is installed?

(REPL is working in Windows command prompt.)

---

I added the JDK to PATH and now I get this message:

```
We couldn't connect.

Looks like there was an issue trying to connect to the project. Here's what we got:
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Program
```

Comment: Is this at startup or when you start an Instarepl?

Comment: When I start the Instarepl?

Comment: Is the jdk in your PATH?

Comment: I am not sure. I have `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` and for `Path` I have `C:\User\a\.lein\bin` Is this correct?

Comment: I added JDK to PATH but now I get a different error, I added to the question.

Comment: Hmm, try throwing this question to the mailing list. They will know more about the internals of LT. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/light-table-discussion

Comment: Also checkout this discussion:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/tstgaTX0quc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, currently anyone wanting to run LT on Win8 is advised to do the following (worked for me in this exact order anyway).

1. Download LT, unpack and move it to desired location.
2. When starting it, press `Ctrl-Space` and type `InstaRepl` to open a new InstaRepl tab.
3. follow the dialog window URI pointing to the Oracle JDK/JRE download for Windows x86_64 (or 32bit I think is available too) at the bottom of the list.
4. Install the JDK and JRE in a location without spaces in the path (like C:\java)
5. Open configuration and change (system) environment variable for PATH: add "C:\java\bin;..." where the semicolon is the separator for paths (colons : in *nix)
6. Download Leiningen for Windows from http://leiningen-win-installer.djpowell.net/
7. It will add its own path to the User Env Vars PATH - I installed it under `C:\.lein`
8. It will fire up a `cmd` window and you will be able to effectively use both `java` and `lein repl` commands to demonstrate it being operable.
9. Finally open LightTable and `Ctrl+Space` then open "Instarepl" and you are ready to go

I had to install en reinstall, reboot a few times because I had fixed the JDK path to match any with no spaces in it, then the leiningen install already referenced it so I had to reinstall that as well so keep in mind the order of these steps matters atm.

Additionally, don't forget to install Maven (binary zip will do) and extract it to any convenient location. I have it in my extra disk under folder "Portable" where also LT resides so `G:\Portable\Maven` in my case. You should add this path e.g. `G:\Portable\Maven\bin` to the system environment variables PATH as well so any CLI tools (cmd, PS, LT) may use Maven to pull in software packages.

Finally you should add `JAVA_HOME` to your environment variables (only the root folder) e.g. `C:\java` so that the `mvn` command can use it freely from anywhere.

One thing I've found myself doing either on Linux or Windows LT is to go to the LT folder clojure plugins folder e.g. `G:\Portable\LightTable\plugins\clojure` and open up the `projects.clj` file to add a single additional `:dependencies` item for `[alembic "LATEST"]`. Then, while in that exact folder, do a quick `lein deps` to pull in the dependencies and you can freely use `(require '[alembic.still :refer (distill)])` and then `(distill '[some-package 1.2.3])` to readily grab any other published packages you desire without leaving the InstaRepl. Pwnage to download, install, classpath and reload the project in one go, the `distill` function takes any number of quoted vectors just like require so you can add this to the `User: behaviors` as a `:lt.plugins.clojure.instarepl/start-content` tag and then do a `Ctrl-r` user keybinding to open a new instarepl tab and immediately have it available to pull in anything you desire.

Perhaps a little elaborate explanation but I've found this workflow to be very suitable for any type of project RAD I wish to do.

Comment: Amazing answer. If you're behind a firewall, also set HTTPS_PROXY through the control panel around step 6. Otherwise lein will fail to install + after you've fixed that, LT will fail to d/l deps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your path has a whitespace that is confusing the startup script. Try installing your JDK in a path without spaces.

Comment: Good point! I installed jdk in C:\Users\a\bin and I still got the same error with C:/Program.

Comment: Now I get connection error. Please see the thread in the group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/Nif7b82DrzY

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Win7 x64, LV v0.6.6.   I'll note that I installed leiningen in a non-standard location, not sure if that triggered this problem.

I got some help from [this link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/21091/error-error-locating-jdk-set-javahome-or-put-javac-and-jarsigner-on-your-path), but the instructions, like the ones in the other answer above, were way more than I needed.

The fix for me was to add the following to my PATH environment variable (Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables... -> User -> Path -> Edit...):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
```

Of course that is system-dependent based on where you installed Java. Unlike others, I had no problems related to spaces in the folder name.

Afterward, open a new command prompt and run "javac". That was not found before, but now it runs, and now Light Table works.

Comment: A more idiomatic way to do this, I guess, is to set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK root folder and then add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH`.